# Using async pipes with map instead of subscribing

Tags: javascript, angular

I am new with `async pipes` and I am trying to use it in my app and I am also getting rid of the `.subscribe()` and instead use `.map()`. My current code works fine. But I am getting a little stuck when I use .map instead of subscribe and then use `| async`.

Below is my current code: Would highly appreciate if someone could provide any inputs.

// component

```
public lhsLinks: Observable<ContactInfoResponse>;
ngOnInit() {
this.getAllLinks();
}
private getAllLinks() {
this.store
.pipe(select(ContactTriageTiles))
.subscribe((contractTiles: any) => {
  const temparray = [];
  const chunksSize = contractTiles.length / 2;
  for (let i = 0, j = contractTiles.length; i < j; i += chunksSize) {
    const elementList = contractTiles.slice(i, i + chunksSize);
    temparray.push(elementList);
  }
  if (temparray.length > 0) {
    this.rhsLinks = temparray[0];
    this.lhsLinks = temparray[1];
  }
});
```

}

// In my html:

```
<div class="row no-gutters" *ngFor="let contact of lhsLinks">
<h3>{{contact.name}}</h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only need the output from `lhsLinks` it should just be a matter of returning that value from the map function

```
public lhsLinks: Observable<ContactInfoResponse>;
ngOnInit() {
this.getAllLinks();
}

private getAllLinks() {
this.lhsLinks = this.store
.pipe(select(ContactTriageTiles))
.map((contractTiles: any) => {
  const temporary = [];
  const chunksSize = contractTiles.length / 2;
  for (let i = 0, j = contractTiles.length; i < j; i += chunksSize) {
    const elementList = contractTiles.slice(i, i + chunksSize);
    temporary.push(elementList);
  }
  if (temporary.length > 0) {
    return temporary[1];
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="row no-gutters" *ngFor="let contact of lhsLinks|async">
<h3>{{contact.name}}</h3>
</div>
```

the async pipe itself will be calling subscribe on the observable you pass in.

if you need rhsLinks as well as lhsLinks values it gets a bit more complex. you might look at returning an object of values and then use "[async as [property]](https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/angular-ngif-async-pipe)" to break things down in your template.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just filter the items to the first half and the second half?

```
contractTiles$ = this.store.pipe(select(ContactTriageTiles));

rhsLinks$ = this.contractTiles$.pipe(
  map(
    // Filter to the first half
    contractTiles => contractTiles.filter(
      (item, index) => index < (contractTiles.length / 2)
    )
  )
);

lhsLinks$ = this.contractTiles$.pipe(
  map(
    // Filter to the second half
    contractTiles => contractTiles.filter(
      (item, index) => index >= (contractTiles.length / 2)
    )
  )
);
```

and in the template use the async pipe

```
<div class="row no-gutters" *ngFor="let contact of lhsLinks$ | async">
  <h3>{{contact.name}}</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: We are not splitting the array here.. both lhs and rhs will return same array!